# Should I use .tar.gz?

Tags: c++, compression, archive

In the Unix world, there is a famous format called "tar.gz".

But now, I want to develop a game and random accessing a file will be more efficient. If it is archived first, it will cause sequential access.

I know that there is an alternative format called zip or 7z, but what about other formats?

Not only gz.tar, I'd like to a minor compressing library and also get archiving features.

**Should I use *.tar or other solutions are available?**

PS: I'm using C++.

Comment: do you mean `.tar.gz` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Random" access is not good on a .tar.gz, since that is a .tar file that has been wrapped in a .gz compression, so to get to things in the .tar file, you'd first have to decompress the .tar file.

It would be possible to use a .tar file that contains individual files compressed with .gz. You can read the table of content of the .tar file and find/store where all the files are in the archive, and then extract as you need. However, you may find that using your own format is "better" (for example, if I remember correctly, the "header" for a tar-archive is a file at a time, you may want to build your header in one lump, before you store the files [which does mean at least enumerating all the relevant files first, then forming the compressed variant and "patching up" the header with the offsets in compressed form]

For a game, one critical factor would probably be the decompression speed, so you may want to look at different libraries and which one has the best decompression speed. I found this when searching for a comparison:
http://catchchallenger.first-world.info//wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO

You may also care about memory usage, which also varies a bit depending on algorithm.

And I'm guessing your individual files will be much smaller than the entire tar-ball of Linux, so you may want to do your own benchmark, with your own data - after all, the speed of different compression formats does, to some degree, depend on the format of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, for computer games, what you need is a format where each file is compressed individually *before* being assembled into one file. This is the crucial difference between .tar.gz and .zip / .7z formats, that is, tar-gz is a "compressed archive" while zip / 7z are "archives of compressed files". In fact, both file formats use the same compression algorithm (by default), and the only reason that .tar.gz files are typically smaller is because they compress the entire archive instead of file-by-file, which increases the overall compression ratio.

AFAIK, most computer games use a zip format or a custom format that closely matches it, because it does per-file compression. For instance, Quake engines have always (.pak, .pk3, .pk4) relied on an off-the-shelf zip format with a few minor additions (like a built-in checksum, I think).

The .tar.gz format is created by first making an archive that puts all the (uncompressed) files into one .tar file. Then, that big archive file is compressed with the gzip method to create the final .tar.gz file. The point is that to get any one of the files from the archive you have the decompress the entire thing. This is very appropriate for backups or large transfers, but not appropriate at all for a game engine media archive.

That said, you could technically do the reverse of tar-gz, which is to compress each file individually with gzip, and then put them together in a .tar archive. But this is probably not worth the extra trouble, as it is pretty much exactly what zip files are (in "one easy step"). So, it will be a lot easier to use an off-the-shelf all-in-one format like zip that will allow you to extract individual files at a time. There are many off-the-shelf libraries for extracting and manipulating files in zip archives, just start with [libzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libzip) (not to be confused with zlib (for gzip or .gz)).

> In the Unix world, there is a famous format called "tar.gz".

Probably the biggest reason why "tar-ballz" are so popular and famously used in Unix-like systems is that they preserve file permissions (and other meta-data, I guess). I think that some implementations of zip and 7z might provide that feature as an extension to the format, but most don't have it. The convenient thing with tar archives is that whatever you put in there comes out exactly the same at the other end, with all permissions and whatever else preserved. And the "gzip" compression (from zlib) has just been historically an industry-standard compression algorithm, although, now, there are better ones, also supported by tar, such as .tar.lzma (or .tlz) or .tar.xz.

> but what about other formats?

There aren't really that many other formats. Mostly, compressed archive formats often reuse the same few algorithms (DEFLATE, LZ77 / LZMA / LZMA2, BZIP, etc.), and often, formats like zip / 7z / rar are only really container formats that can employ any of those compression algorithms (and even mix and match depending on the individual file types). The point is that you won't really find much that is better than zip or 7z. And their competitors are more or less gone today (like rar?).

> Should I use *.tar or other solutions are available?

No, use zip or 7z. Tar-balls are for backups. They are optimized for that purpose (e.g., dump a large folder full of files into a tar-ball, and recover it later, with everything preserved and with best full-archive compression). For your application, zip or 7z is more appropriate.

Comment: `7z` archives also allow [solid compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_compression) which is more similar to the approach used by archive-then-compress - only with a variable block size that allows you to strike a balance between random seek performance and file size on a per-archive basis.